# Failed to attach acpi gpio chip

Tags: usb

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS and trying to attach a Zwave USB dongle. I get an error saying, "cp210x 1-1:1.1: Failed to attach ACPI GPIO chip". The device won't show up.

I've searched and only found things on older versions.  I do see cp210x loaded when I issue `lsmod|grep cp210x`.

Thank you for your help